# Displaying results from two tables in two different divs with a single function using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

```js
$(".search").click(function() {
       a=  $(".input").val();
        $.post("search_input.php", {search:a}, function(resp) {
        if (resp!= 'incorrect') {
       $('#first').html(resp);
         }
       else{
     $('#first').html('no result found');
     }
   })

})
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="search">Search</button>
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

At search_input.php, I tried searching two different tables with search.

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * from names_tb WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'");
$result2 = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * from places_tb WHERE location LIKE '%$search%'");
```

My major issue is this, how can I display the result of result1 in the first div and the result for result2 in the second div using php? I tried using echo

```
$first=mysqli_num_rows($result1);
        if ($first>0) {

while ($b=$result1->fetch_array()) {

            $name=$b['name'];
            $age= $b['age'];
         }
} else{
            echo "incorrect";
        }
 $second=mysqli_num_rows($result2);
        if ($second>0) {

while ($c=$result2->fetch_array()) {

            $location=$b['location'];
            $state= $b['state'];
         }
} else{
            echo "incorrect";
        }
```

But the problem with this is that, it will only display one of the results in the first div leaving the second div empty.
Again, my main issue is to display result1 in the first div and result2 in the second div, how can I do this?

Comment: Fetch the results using a single query . put 4 different values in one single array and split the array in JQuery . Now you can easily display the results in respective divs .

Comment: Thanks, I got a clue but not perfect. I used json_encode($array); when I tried to retrieve the first value of my array in ajax, it didn't work well. Let's say my array[0] is 'incomplete', If I tried to retrieve array[0], it bring [, if I tried to retrieve array[1], it will bring ', if I tried to retrieve array[2], it will bring i, if array[3], it will bring n, if array[4], it will bring c,(spelling incomplete, letter by letter). Meanwhile, I stored 'incomplete' as a word, not letter by letter, I expect the word to be there, not retrieving it, letter by letter. I hope you get my question.

Comment: try my method and send incomplete if no result , it will solve your purpose .

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Yes, I would have marked your contribution as the answer but I can't find the mark sign so I upvoted it as a useful comment

Comment: I'm putting it as an answer kindly mark it .